Phaseshift Histogram for Matlab
I want to create a phaseshift histogram with Matlab. I have values from -180 degrees to +180 degrees and want to plot those occurences in a circle either from the -180 to +180 degrees or just the values from the variable (shift_values) which are somewhere from -15 to 180 degrees.
I tried this but it still shows 0 to 360 degrees!
all_shifts_combined = cat(1, all_shifts{:});

valid_shifts = all_shifts_combined(all_shifts_combined >= -180 & all_shifts_combined <= 180);

edges = linspace(-180, 180, 360); % Ein Bin pro Grad

counts = histcounts(valid_shifts, edges);

theta = deg2rad(edges(1:end-1)); % Konvertiere Bin-Kanten in Radiant
polarplot(theta, counts, 'DisplayName', 'Shifts');

title('Distribution of Shifts');
legend('Location', 'northoutside');
grid on;


What you want exactly is a little bit unclear. Do you want to keep the exact same plot (as in the location of your points are correct), but just have the angle labels displayed as going from -180deg to 180deg? Do you want your zero angle to be somewhere else? Do you want increasing angles in the clockwise or counter-clockwise direction? All of these are possible by modifying the polaraxis object inside of which your data is plotted
